# Force links to open in SharePoint mobile application

Tags: sharepoint-online, mobile

We are launching a new Intranet that we would like our employees to open in the SharePoint mobile app for the best experience. Every link I test opens in the browser by default.

Can we force the links to open in the mobile app (android / IOS)? The links we will send out in communication emails are aspx pages, not documents stored in SharePoint.